# Help on calculus surface area?

Tags: calculus

[image: Here is the question guys!]

[image: My solution is below...]
I solved it and the answer did not turn out correct! according to the math web server that I submitted it to.

Thoughts???
Thanks guys!

[image: I used this formula]
Here is the formula! But I used dx of course instead of dy. Becuase it is rotating around the x-axis. y is basically x. I found the derivative and plugged it into the 'X part of the formula and then put the plugged the original into the x part. A=o B=8.

Comment: You want $\sqrt{1+81x^4}$. Forgot to square the derivative.

Comment: Just edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we rotate the part of the curve $y=f(x)$, from $x=a$ to $x=b$, around the $x$-axis, then the surface area is
$$\int_{x=a}^b 2\pi f(x)\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\,dx.$$

In our case, $a=0$ and $b=8$, and $f(x)=3x^3$. It follows that $f'(x)=9x^2$. Thus our surface area is
$$\int_0^8 (2\pi)(3x^3)\sqrt{1+81x^4}\,dx.$$
For the integration, let $u=1+81x^4$.

Comment: You are welcome. Just a small slip in the initial setup. Made the integration a lot harder.